# Linux file explorer with Windows-like visual disk management?

Tags: software-recommendation, disk-usage, filemanager

Is there any file manager that looks like Windows Explorer? I mean, when I download a large file, I want to know which of my partitions have sufficient empty space, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Windows File Explorer]

Is there any file manager for Linux that has this feature?

Comment: Should it be a GUI file-manager, or can it be a terminal one? What exactly is the feature you are after? The filled bar? Or is any indication, even if textual (i.e., a label with `67% free`) enough?